# Is it possible to search in PhpStorm debugger view?

Tags: phpstorm

Like in topic, is there any option to find something in PhpStorm Debugger view?

For example I want to find element `39001421` in:

[image]

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you can .. but **only** in already expanded nodes -- it will search the node names. For that just start typing -- as it would be any other list/tree (Project or Structure View etc).

Comment: @LazyOne Unfortunately it doesn't seems to work right. I  have started typing what i am looking for but it have selected completely another item. Maybe i am doing something wrong ? :/

Comment: Seems to work OK for me. If you can provide some simple code to reproduce it and tell what key I need to look (and tell how you are looking) then I can try it here. **But in any case:** try ordering the items (option under "cog" icon I think)

Comment: @LazyOne Do You have got any idea where can i find "cog" icon?

Comment: Ok i have found it. It is just gear icon on the left side of debugger: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ass4AfKIPqNpsRUcZjbQ1RRo7yJo

Comment: @LazyOne if i type 39001421 it select 36900312 item every time... Do You have any idea why it do so ?

Comment: No idea: here are my screenshots (notice the search that I did and what it found): 1) http://postimg.org/image/r52v8yekf/ 2) https://postimg.org/image/p7vyy34fn/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127646/discussion-between-dominik-and-lazyone).

Comment: Please note that I'm using 2016.3 EAP. But it should be the same in current stable 2016.2. (I can only see that you are must be using xdebug older than 2.4 .. but it should have no impact on search (but you may try hiding the addresses)

Comment: I had to use xdebug-2.3.2 because 2.4 version had had problems with show SimpleXMLElements. I will try to search with disable variable adresses in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LazyOne Did a great job. With his help i think that i have found most effectively way to find something in PhpStorm debugger view. (if you are curious how we were looking for that answer please read comments beneath first post)

[image]

1. Firstly You should shut off variable adress view. (picture 1)
2. Secondly You should ensure that You have got "Sort Values Alphabetically" option sellected. (dropdown menu inside "gear" icon, picture 2)
3. Thirdly You should expand what You want to looking in (picture 3)
4. Next, You can type what You want to search for, If You don't find what you want to find, simply press up or down arrow to show next "occurence".

Comment: This is a helpful explanation of how you solved this query.

Comment: @Martin Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a simple Ctrl-F works here. Here's one way to do it.

When you hit your breakpoint, press Alt-F8 or from the menu, choose `Run -> Evaluate expression`. In the window that opens, simply input the expression you would like to evaluate; in your case, something like

```
$items[39001421]
```

You'll get the value you're looking for at the bottom of the window.

Comment: Thank You for answer. In my PhpStorm is Ctrl+U for Evaluating expression. This may be because i have got Eclipse keymapping. But i have got problem. $items array is in the pricelist object and when i right-click $items and select evaluate expression it suggest me to evaluate `$pricelist->items` i click evaluate and it show me `ERROR EVALUATING CODE`. What can cause that?